# click event not triggering in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, gis

I am using leaflet.js for my application.
The click event is not triggering alongwith the mouseover event.

```
   layer.on({
                mouseover: function (e) {
                    L.popup().setLatLng(e.latlng)
                    .setContent("Test")
                    .openOn(map);
                },
                click: function () {
                    alert("Click");
                    map.fire("click", e);
                }
            });
```

I am using the custom marker instead of circle marker

```
    option.pointToLayer = function (feature, latlng) {
   var marker = L.marker(latlng);
                    var icon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'Image/InvestmentIcons/environmentalflow.png',
            iconSize: [12, 12], // size of the icon
        });

                        marker.options.icon = icon;
                        return marker;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that when a user tries to click on your Marker (which would trigger your `"click"` event listener, i.e. display your `alert`), they have to move first their mouse over the Marker, which opens a Popup at this position (accordingly with your `"mouseover"` event listener), so the Popup is now receiving the click, instead of your Marker.

You can see that your `"click"` listener is still working properly by positioning your mouse cursor just besides the Popup "tip", where it does not cover the Marker icon, but the mouse cursor is still somehow a little bit on the Marker:

[image: Screenshot mouse cursor next to Popup tip to click on Marker]

To try it live: https://plnkr.co/edit/8Zu0cYeYATp2qY6ltn7N?p=preview

To avoid this UX issue, you could try using a [Tooltip](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#tooltip) instead of a Popup for example. By default it will appear on the side of the coordinates, instead of above it (which makes the Popup cover the Marker).